# how to reference the same keys in mongoose schema with the same value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const _Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: Number,
  key_example:[{
    // I want the same name and age as above 
    name,
    age
  }] 
})

const model = mongoose.model("person" , _Schema)

async function CreateAndSave () {
  const _Person = new model({name:"mohe", age:33})
  await _Person.save()
}

CreateAndSave()

// in mongodDB
{
  name: "mohe",
  age: 33,
  key_example:[{
    name: "mohe",
    age: 33
  }]
}
```

How can I make keys that reference other keys. So I can type the value and the reset copy from referenced key. I hope you understand my question.